# App crashes when returning from child activity

Tags: android, camera

I'm trying to use the camera on my Android application, but when it should return to the MainActivity, the application simply closes itself. I'm doing it like this:
In MainActivity, there is a button that opens a dialog, and if the user clicks Yes, it starts the AddInfo activity from a class that implements the OnClickListener, like this:

```
alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(fonte, AddInfo.class);
                    fonte.startActivityForResult(intent, 10);
                }
            });
```

"fonte" is an Activity that I set its reference to the MainActivity on the constructor of this class.
Inside that AddInfo activity, there is a button that opens the device camera, it looks like this:

[image]

That "Tirar Foto" button is the one that calls the camera, and it calls a method named CaptureImage, which takes the photo and store it on the phone, and when it returns to the AddInfo activity, I save the Bitmap on a global variable I have on AddInfo, and show a preview of the photo in the place of that camera image. When I click the OK button, I want the AddInfo activity to return to the MainActivity returning that Bitmap and those two strings. I'm doing it this way:

```
buttOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                titulo = editTit.getText().toString();
                descricao = editDesc.getText().toString();
                Intent output = new Intent();
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString("titulo",titulo);
                b.putString("descricao",descricao);
                b.putParcelable("foto", fotoTirada);
                output.putExtra("dados", b);
                setResult(5,output);
                finish();
            }
        });
```

It was working without any problem before I put the photo thing on the AddInfo, but now, when I click that OK button, the application just crashes without any exception or warning like "The app stopped". The AddInfo also has an OnActivityResult, which is where it previews the photo taken, so I think the problem is that since the AddInfo calls the camera, and returns from there, when it returns, it's no more the activity that the MainActivity called, and then the      `setResult` doesn't work. But if this is really the problem, I don't know how I could fix this. So, anyone can help me?

EDIT:
This appeared in logcat when I clicked the OK button:

```
11-24 13:01:06.064 7392-7423/com.example.portol.agendalocal2 I/GMPM: App measurement is starting up
11-24 13:01:06.073 7392-7423/com.example.portol.agendalocal2 E/GMPM: getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10
11-24 13:01:06.075 7392-7423/com.example.portol.agendalocal2 E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
```

EDIT2:
I just discovered something. If I don't take the photo, be it by cancelling it, or by not opening the camera, the app doesn't crash, it just crashes when I take the photo and save it.

Comment: `The app stopped` always provides a stacktrace. Please insert it in your question.

Comment: I have a feeling this could be easily resolved if you tried to debug the application yourself.

Comment: But I don't get the message "The app stopped", it just crashes. And I already tried to debug the application, but after it calls that `finish()`, the application crashes

Comment: So, take a look in logcat and you will see the stacktrace about the error

Comment: @DeividiCavarzan See the Edit I made on the original post

Comment: There's no call to `getGoogleAppId` in the code you posted. A crash surely has a stacktrace on logcat, look harder (or just filter by Error level or "exception" keyword).

Comment: I just tried to filter by Error level and it just shows what I wrote in the last edit, also, trying to filter by exception doesn't show anything

Comment: Do not filter (let it verbose) and see if something else happens.

Comment: I just discovered something. If I don't take the photo, be it by cancelling it, or by not opening the camera, the app doesn't crash, it just crashes when I take the photo and save it. Also, I don't know if this is relevant, but when I actually take the photo, and click on the OK button, the logcat cleans itself and write some things.